# What is considered a patent?

Tags: patentability, copyright

I have an idea for a mechanical over Unity that uses magnets with different Tesla values to keep and add energy into a perpetual system. I don't have the money for a patent because I'm poor and on SSI. I'd like make money off of this were I could have a better life than what I have.

The thing I'm wondering is that in this day and age of online blogging and blog sites that publish your material you submit.

In this case two diagrams and an explanation of my idea. Could a copyright or thus a copyright because the material is published though the site, be used as a viable patent.